# Styling HTML with odd/even colors

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a HTML table which prints Active Record objects created on different dates, for
example: `day1,day1,day2,day2,day3`.

I want to print every day in an alternate color, every `day1` in grey, every `day2` in white and every `day3` in grey again.

The code I have written is:

```
color = true

objects.each_with_index do |object, index|
  if object[index-1].date == object.date
   color = true
  else
   color = false
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [the `cycle` method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-cycle):

```
objects.each_with_index do |object, index|
  color = cycle('grey', 'white')
  # etc.
end
```

Following your comment, you could do the following:

```
objects.each_with_index do |object, index|
  color = object.date.even? ? :grey : :white
  # etc.
end
```

Comment: that will cycle through grey and white in every alternate values. I want it to have same color for same date, example: all march 15th record will have grey and all march 16th will have white and all march 18th will have grey again.

Comment: See my update : If the date's day number in the month is even (example: today 16th of march 2016, 16 is even), then the color will be grey, if not the color will be white.

Comment: Your update could work if there wasn't ant holydays, there might come two odd or even days one after another.

Comment: You didn't give that constraint on your original question. Please be explicit in your demand and list all your constraints clearly

Answer (score 0):

I think the logic is fine, but you can refactor it to this:

```
objects.each_with_index do |object, index|
  color = object[index-1].date == object.date
end
```